# I'm getting NULL parameter when I request for auth2 token in Asp.net WebAPI?

Tags: c#, angular, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, angular-httpclient

I have a web API the authentication method is auth2. It is working fine when I run it in POSTMAN successfully data get and post, Token get successfully and post successfully. I face the problem when I send request from angular7 method the request successfully sent but parameter(UserName, Password) got NULL. Please let me know where is the problem.
The WebApi and Angular code are below.

Angular Code:

```
 ApiTokenUrl='http://localhost:49978/token';
 UserAuthentication(UserName: string,Password: string):Observable<any>{
 let data="username=" + UserName + "&password=" + Password +  "&grant_type=password";  
 var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.ApiTokenUrl,data,   {headers:reqHeader});
   }
```

When I use the debugger in OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class and check the parameters(UserName, Password) got NULL
the request canceled from the below method because it found parameter NULL so request no forward.

WebApi Code:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public override async Task     ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {

        context.Validated(); 
    }
```

ScreenShots are below 
[image]

Comment: Content type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @shyambabu Thank you very much for your suggestion I got the answer actually I was missing one statement that is  app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); in startup.cs file

Comment: That is great to hear that you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Actually, I was missing the highlighted statement in startup.cs file